# Cloning a single branch from a git repo

Tags: git, git-branch, git-bash, tortoisegit, git-clone

I've tried several time to clone a single branch from a git repo provided by my Org. 
I tried with git bash , tortoise but every time when i try to clone a single branch it started cloning the whole repo. Is there any particular solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command to solve your issue.
`git clone --single-branch --branch <branchname> <remote-repo>`